# LLhood for t-dis

Tags: distribution

What is the mistake in the following code for the loglikelihood function of the t-distribution:

```
loglike <- function(p,x){
  mu <- p[1]
  sgm <- p[2]
  df <- p[3}
 ll <- dt((x-mu)/sgm, df=d)
 sum(log(ll)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed dividing by sigma because of the cdf:

```
loglike <- function(p,x){
  mu <- p[1]
  sgm <- p[2]
  df <- p[3}
 ll <- dt((x-mu)/sgm, df=d)\sgm
 sum(log(ll)
}
```

Same if you want to calculate the LL for the normal distribution:

```
loglike <- function(p,x){
  mu <- p[1]
  sgm <- p[2]
 ll <- dnorm((x-mu)/sgm)/sgm
sum(log(ll)
}
```

You again divide by sigma